# Использовать JSMPP для отправки SMS сообщений

Tags: java

После успешного конекта к серверу после отправки сообщения, результат не приходит к пользователю. Ошибок при отправки нет. Но в реальности сообщение не доставляется.

```
private final static String TELEPHONE_NUMBER = "380954458675";

 GeneralDataCoding coding = new GeneralDataCoding(
                    Alphabet.ALPHA_UCS2,
                    MessageClass.CLASS0,
                    false);

 String messageId = session.submitShortMessage(
                    "CMT",
                    TypeOfNumber.ALPHANUMERIC,
                    NumberingPlanIndicator.UNKNOWN,
                    "ACME",
                    TypeOfNumber.NATIONAL,
                    NumberingPlanIndicator.NATIONAL,
                    TELEPHONE_NUMBER,
                    new ESMClass(),
                    (byte)0,   // (byte)0
                    (byte)1,  // (byte)1
                    null,
                    null,
                    new RegisteredDelivery(SMSCDeliveryReceipt.DEFAULT),
                    (byte)0, // (byte)0
                    coding,
                    (byte)0,
                    "jSMPP simplify SMPP on Java platform".getBytes());
```

Пробовал разные форматы телефонного номера **380**, **+380**, **81038** но сообщение не доставляется.

Также после отправки отрабатывает метод: `onAcceptDeliverSm`

Comment: Как для чего? Имя пользователя и пароль от SMPP-сервера. У вас какой установлен?

Comment: А существует сервер с триальным периодом, или с ограниченным количеством sms. В котором предоставят логин и пароль.?

Comment: Есть бесплатные сервера. Например. [kannel](http://www.kannel.org/). Подключай к машине мобилку или 3g-модем, настраивай сервак и можно рассылать. Можно kannel подключить не к устройству, а к вышестояюшему smpp-серверу самого ОПСОСа. Но это уже деньги и соответствие жёстким требованиям. Или можно вообще не устанавливать локальный сервак, а воспользоваться чужим.Гугль выдаёт множество вариантов по запросу "SMPP server". У кого-то, возможно, и триал найдётся.

Comment: Спасибо нашел SMPP сервер с 10 бесплатными смс.
Но сообщение не доставляется, хотя ошибок при отправки нет.
Описание вопроса изменил.

Comment: @JAVAvladuxa, ссылкой на `SMPP сервер с 10 бесплатными смс` не поделитесь?

Comment: https://turbosms.ua/ Если получится отправить смс используя jsmpp java library, то маякните